# Build folder contains a dll file that causes issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[I only want the autofib.dll file in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VjTy.png)

Before I added a new package this would never be outputted to the folder, is there a way to store those two files from appearing in the folder when I build the project as I only want autofib.dll in there.

Comment: What is your actual problem, why do have a phobia of dependencies? If you explain this we might be able to tender a work-around

Comment: it is not needed since the program uses the dll as a custom script, when the other dll and file is in the folder it causes the program to not detect anything

Comment: Is this a meta trader plugin by any chance?

Comment: No it is for another program quantower

Comment: Why couldn't you modify the detector program? Query by name. From the information you have provided so far, I couldn't know why these two dlls entered your folder.